# How to refresh a card from modal HTML dialog boxes?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am building a Workspace add-on (in contrast to an Editor add-on). I have successfully created a modal dialog box using the following code:

```
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('dialog.html')
      .setWidth(600)
      .setHeight(425)
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Some title here...');
```

I can successfully call an Apps Script (server side) function from the dialog.html JavaScript using this syntax:

```
google.script.run.withFailureHandler(showError).withSuccessHandler(closeThisWindow).onAppsScriptFunction(p1, p2);
```

On the Apps Script side, I have the function that receives the arguments (p1, p2) from the JavaScript function:

```
function onAppsScriptFunction(p1, p2) {
  console.log(p1 + p2);

  // the following does not work
  // it simply does nothing
  return CardService.newCardBuilder()
      .addSection(
        CardService.newCardSection().addWidget(
          CardService.newTextParagraph().setText("This never appears")
          )
      )
      .build();
}
```

Everything works as expected, except -- the card is not updated/refreshed. I have digged through all the Apps Script documentation and I don't see how can I refresh the sidebar or card.
Is there a way to initiate a refresh / redraw / restart / anything from the client-side JavaScript. I also tried various combinations with `CardService.newActionResponseBuilder() and setStateChanged(true) and setNavigation` but nothing works.

Or if that's not possible, at least somehow visually act after a user closes the Modal HTML dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You can only update the card from a context of an Addon trigger

In your case `onAppsScriptFunction` is not linked to the Addon and thus cannot update the content of the Addon sidebar.

**A workaround would be to deploy your modal dialog as a [WebApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web).**

- In this case, you can call the WebApp with [setOpenLink](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/button#setOpenLink(OpenLink))
- You can prompt the Add-on to reload when the WebApp is closed with [setOnClose(CardService.OnClose.RELOAD_ADD_ON))](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/open-link?hl=vi&authuser=2#setoncloseonclose)

- In combination with [script properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) you can write something like:

*Code.gs*

```js
function onAppsScriptFunction(p1, p2) {
  console.log(p1 + p2);  
  var props = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  props.setProperty("update", "yes");
  
}

function onHomepage() {  
  var props = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var update = props.getProperty("update");
  if(update == null || update == "no"){   

    var url =ScriptApp.getService().getUrl(); 
  
    var button = CardService.newTextButton()
    .setText("Open modal dialog as WebApp")
    .setOpenLink(CardService.newOpenLink()
                 .setUrl(url)
                 .setOnClose(CardService.OnClose.RELOAD_ADD_ON));   
    var buttonSet = CardService.newButtonSet().addButton(button)    
    return CardService.newCardBuilder()
            .addSection(CardService.newCardSection().addWidget(buttonSet))
    .build();
    
  }  
  else{
    props.setProperty("update", "no");
    return CardService.newCardBuilder()
            .addSection(CardService.newCardSection()
              .addWidget(CardService.newTextParagraph().setText("This now appears")))
    .build();
  }
}

function doGet(){
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('dialog.html')
  .setWidth(600)
  .setHeight(425);
  
  return html; 
}
```

*dialog.html:*

```
<html>
  <script>
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(success).onAppsScriptFunction(100, 150);
    function success() {
      window.top.close();
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

- After deploying your code as a WEbApp this sample snippet will update your Addon sidebar as desired after the opened window is closed again.
- Please mind that depending on your use case you need to decide how to deploy the WebApp and which of the PropertiesServices is the most suitbale for you (script, user or document properties).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! In my case I am not able to publish a WebApp, so this is not an option for me. Also, I am using a modal dialog for "Google Picker API" and it is already too much overhead for a simple browse dialog. I will accept your answer if there is no other solution.

Comment: If there is another solution, I will also be happy to know about it :-) But is there any reason you cannot migrate the functionality of your modal dialog to a WebApp? Especially for large / complex contents a WebApp gives you many more options and freedom in design than a simple dialog.

Comment: I just need a simple browse for a file dialog. It should be max 3 lines of code. Using the modal dialog is already too much overhead. Publishing a web app seems like a lot more complexity for a simple thing. Also, most probably we are abandoning the Google platform altogether, because Google is not fixing a bug (for years) that affects all files with 17+ pages. https://issuetracker.google.com/u/0/issues/171728028 That's a huge red flag!